# Get the corresponding features back from OneHotEncoder

Tags: python, machine-learning, feature-selection, one-hot-encoding

I was trying to do some data analysis on some features in my dataset after converting the features with OneHotEncoder, and the output shows that feature 13 and feature 21 are the most significant features, but how would I know which features do these correspond to?

Comment: Has the answer solved your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the `.categories_` attribute. This is a general example:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

ohe = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)

arr = np.random.choice(['dog', 'cat', 'ferret'], 10)
print(arr)
```

```py
Out[100]: 
array(['ferret', 'ferret', 'dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'ferret', 'ferret',
       'ferret', 'dog', 'dog'], dtype='<U6')
```

```
encoded = ohe.fit_transform(arr.reshape(-1, 1))
print(encoded)
```

```py
[[0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]]
```

```
print(ohe.categories_) # this is the line you're looking for
```

```py
Out[1]: [array(['cat', 'dog', 'ferret'], dtype='<U6')]
```

Now just index this array to find your 16th and 21st feature.